# One to Many Assosiation without a collection on many Side EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations, one-to-many

I have a BaseEntity Like This :

```
public class BaseEntity<T>
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
        this.createdDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        this.updatetdDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column("ID")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.
        DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public T id { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("Created_by")]
    public virtual BonchaghWebApplication.Models.Core.User createdBy { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKey("Updated_by")]

    public virtual BonchaghWebApplication.Models.Core.User updatedBy { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public DateTime updatetdDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and another like this :

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("App_User")]
public class User:BaseEntity<long>
{
    public String userName { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }


}
```

and these two have one to many relation, I don't need a collection on user side, I say that the record saved by a user and it doesn't matter the user save witch records

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: in this case EF needs a collection in user side to detect many to one association, and this has an error

Comment: If it has an error, please include that error in your question.

Comment: i know the solution to fix the error , the solution is add a collection in user model but i don't want use it , i think it's not good to do this , it's not useful add a collection to user model

Comment: and if add a Collection in User model ,field add in table in database

Comment: Please use the edit link below the question and explain clearly in your question what you want to achieve, what you have tried, and what issues your are having.